# What is hex code 57 in the context of an LDAP authentication error code 49?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, authentication

I have the following error when using [Apache Directory Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/) to log into an AD server:

```
[LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0c0904DB, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 57,v1db1]
```

I have been searching but I haven't found any reference to the hex code 57 on [Ldapwiki](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Common%20Active%20Directory%20Bind%20Errors) or anywhere else.

Comment: It's more likely that the number 57 is not significant. 80090308 points to some type of credential error. Use a 3rd party LDAP tool connect to AD using same user, see if that works first.

Comment: @strongline Apache Directory Studio is the 3rd party tool that's showing the error. Result code 49, http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS, is all about credentials error. The data hex code(s) specify what exactly the issue is with credentials, see the Ldap wiki link, except 57 isn't listed.

Comment: I meant a different tool such as openLDAP to ensure that credential provided is indeed correct. If the other tool works, we can then focus on how credential is provided in Apache.

Comment: @strongline it would seem the problem boiled down to the authentication type which was previously MD5-DIGEST. Once I changed it to simple I was able to log in.
Still it would be nice if hex code 57 were documented somewhere.